# Transfer .xls files through POST request in Java REST Api

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, request-mapping

I'm new to Spring and I have some troubles in receiving a .xls file from the front-end through a POST request. Bassicaly when I accesss the link "Project/File" I receive error code 400(bad request) but the parameters names are the same both in front-end and back-end.

Here is my code so far:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;

    @Consumes("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    @RequestMapping(value = "Project/File",
            method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET},
            params = {"inputXLS"})
    public @ResponseBody void getCitiriContoriMecanici(
            @RequestParam(value = "inputXLS" , required = true) InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{

        //transform the InputStream to an array of bytes;
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        //create a new .xls file
        File file = new File("TEST.xls");  
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //write a the bytes to a new .xls file
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        fileService.getFileFromFrontEnd();//this method is used to parse the .xls file
    }

}
```

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question with what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement a file upload control with a Jax-RS `@Consumes` annotation.  The first problem I see is that you're trying to directly consume `application/vnd.ms-excel`, but that's not what your file upload will present coming from your front end.  It expects `multipart/form-data` as the mime type.  Doing that, you can then have a `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` parameter on your request mapping to get a hold of the file.

I've never used Jax-RS annotations in my application, but you wouldn't even need it.  Your request mapping can be as simple as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="Project/File", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

Spring has a nice guide showing what you need to do for file upload if you want to see further details https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

I should also note, you've annotated the return type of your mapping with `@RequestBody`, but your return type is `void`, so there's no need for `@RequestBody` in this case.  I'd suggest at least having a return type of `HttpStatus` and then returning `HttpStatus.OK` if the upload succeeded.